# Resampling aggregation per group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe like the following

```
             ID         A           B        date
0    0C0003fi8E         6          10  2015-04-01
1    0C0AD3fi4S        10          15  2015-04-01
2    0C0AD3flmn        60          22  2015-04-01
3    0C0003fi8E        10          40  2015-04-02
4    0C0AD3fi4S         8          15  2015-04-02
5    0CaAD3flmn        33          18  2015-04-02
6    0C0003fi8E        10          19  2015-04-03
7    0C0AD3fi4S         8          25  2015-04-03
8    0CaAD3flmn        33          20  2015-04-03
9    0C0003fi8E        75          11  2015-04-04
10   0C0AD3fi4S         4          37  2015-04-04
11   0CaAD3flmn        28          80  2015-04-04
...
```

I need to aggregate `A` and `B` every two consecutive days *for each* ID.

The result should just be one value of `A` and `B` for every `ID` and every X days.

For example, using a sampling frequency of every two days on `ID`:

```
             ID         A           B        date
     0C0003fi8E        16          50  2015-04-01
     0C0AD3fi4S        18          30  2015-04-01
     0C0AD3flmn        93          40  2015-04-01
     0C0003fi8E        95          30  2015-04-03
     0C0AD3fi4S        12          52  2015-04-03
     0CaAD3flmn        61         100  2015-04-03
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

---

What if I want to do re-sampling using more flexible time periods? E.g. every **week**, or every **month**? Can [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) be used for this?

Comment: I understand a chosen answer has been accepted but your needs may be better handled in SQL as grouping, sorting, and aggregation is involved. Does your data frame derive from a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the date as the index you can use TimeGrouper:

```
In [11]: df1.groupby(["ID", pd.TimeGrouper("d")]).sum()
Out[11]:
                        A   B
ID         date
0C0003fi8E 2015-04-01   6  10
           2015-04-02  10  40
           2015-04-03  10  19
           2015-04-04  75  11
0C0AD3fi4S 2015-04-01  10  15
           2015-04-02   8  15
           2015-04-03   8  25
           2015-04-04   4  37
0C0AD3flmn 2015-04-01  60  22
0CaAD3flmn 2015-04-02  33  18
           2015-04-03  33  20
           2015-04-04  28  80

In [12]: df1.groupby(["ID", pd.TimeGrouper("2d")]).sum()
Out[12]:
                        A    B
ID         date
0C0003fi8E 2015-04-01  16   50
           2015-04-03  85   30
0C0AD3fi4S 2015-04-01  18   30
           2015-04-03  12   62
0C0AD3flmn 2015-04-01  60   22
0CaAD3flmn 2015-04-01  33   18
           2015-04-03  61  100
```

*Note: you can `reset_index` to turn the index columns if necessary.*

This isn't explicitly in the docs but [several examples in the cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/cookbook.html#resampling).

Comment: Thank you @Andy. Very helpful as always! May I ask for your thoughts on the difference between this approach and the one from Alexander?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina This is more efficient, mainly as it doesn't require the unstack > op > stack (which creates lots of copies, and from 1d to 2d to 1d), but also as there's misdirection by grouping by date then resampling rather than resampling directly. Also/clearly my answer is more concise / easier to reason about. :)

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina also this answer handles missing data, where the .iloc[::2] style solutions would not. Though tbh I'm not sure I fully understand the df2 slicing. :s That's pretty hairy IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily resample weekly or monthly as follows (weekly shown):

```
>>> df.groupby(['date', 'ID']).sum().unstack().resample('1W').stack()
                               A          B
date       ID                              
2015-04-05 0C0003fi8E  25.250000  20.000000
           0C0AD3fi4S   7.500000  23.000000
           0C0AD3flmn  60.000000  22.000000
           0CaAD3flmn  31.333333  39.333333
```

Regarding your initial request, it is unclear how you want to treat gaps in dates.  For example, do you want to group on consecutive calendar days or consecutive daily observations?

Here is one method:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['date', 'ID']).sum().unstack('ID')
>>>  (df2.iloc[::2, :] + df2.iloc[1::2, :].values).stack('ID')
                        A    B
date       ID                 
2015-04-01 0C0003fi8E  16   50
           0C0AD3fi4S  18   30
2015-04-03 0C0003fi8E  85   30
           0C0AD3fi4S  12   62
           0CaAD3flmn  61  100
```

Comment: Thanks! @Andy has an interesting point about efficiency and robustness (handling missing data). I thought it would be helpful to point you to it.